# Unable to identify objects

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, frame

My webelement is inside a frame and i need to traverse through lot of div's inside the particular frame to reach to my required element.

Could you guys help me out in identifying it.

Tried with SwitchTo(), css selector() but not able to fix it.

Thanks in advance

```
<iframe id="ext-gen472" class=" ux-mif" frameborder="0" name="mif-comp-109379" style="overflow: auto; width: 1370px; height: 268px;" src="/SM9QA/cwc/nav.menu?name=navStart&id=ROOT%2FService%20Desk%2FRegister%20New%20Interaction"> `<div id="X49Edit" class="mandatoryFieldStyle">


<input id="X49" type="text" scripttype="text" value="" onblur=" applyToSameControl(this); " onclick="handleOnClick(this, event);" onchange="handleOnChange(this, event);" onfocus="handleOnFocus(this, event);" onkeyup="handleOnChange(this, event);" maxlength="100" style="width:100%; height:100%;" tabindex="" sctype="Text" datatype="string" buttonid="" dvdvar="" name="instance/title">
```

`

Answer (score 1):

try this code ....

```
 List<WebElement> frameList=driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    System.out.println(frameList.size());
```

Comment: @Bhumipatil : You may want to accept the answer if it solved your query. This is required if someone else stumble upon similar issue ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bhumi did you tried switching of frames.
try using -

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen472")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("X49"));
```